# Fastest way of accessing an image in Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, io, resource-files

What is the fastest way of accessing an image file (`.png`) that is in the project and setting it as the icon of something?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are asking? Are you having performance issues with loading images or are you simply curious?

Comment: I just wanted to change icon of a button everytime it is clicked, and by doing this, i think i must setIcon to the image file that i get

Comment: In that case, why don't you create a instance of every icon you need ahead-of-time?

Comment: `ImageIcon icon1 = ...; ImageIcon icon2 = ...;` and in your action listener you just swap them out.

Comment: But how do you get the image and set it?

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest way"?  Rendering an image will always take time; loading an image will always take time. You could use some pre-caching and/or make sure the color models are compatible, but that all needs more context, for example, if you're loading 4k images, you might not have enough memory to load many simultanously

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what performance gains you expect from different solutions, since this task is mainly I/O-based. To load a `.png` from a file and set it as the icon of a button, you can do the following:

```
File theFile = ...;
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(theFile.toURI().toURL()));
```

Comment: [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) would be a more robust solution as it won't invoke a background thread to load the image and will throw an exception if the file can't be read for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I recently just figure it out and it turns out to be like this `button.setIcon(new.javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.png")));`